# How to animate 2 elements on scroll from side to center then back to side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to control the horizontal movement of 2 elements with scroll: one coming from left, the other from right and make them meet at the center (when they are in the center of the window), then make them return to their initial position as you continue to scroll.

And the reverse of this should happen when you scroll back to top. Also, I am trying to make this movement scale for any device.

This is what I tried:
https://jsfiddle.net/h8voaqm5/2/

```
<div class="scroll-image">
      <img src="" class="circle from-left"/>
      <img src="" class="circle from-right"/>
</div>
```

```
    var total = $(window).height() - current;

// select elements
    var eleRight = $(".from-right");
    var eleLeft = $(".from-left");

// select their start position
    var currPositionRight = eleRight.position().left;
    var currPositionLeft = eleLeft.position().left;

    var win = $(window).height()/2;
    var trackLength = $(window).width()/2; // movement should be from 0 to 50 vw

$(window).scroll(function (event) {

var start = $(".circle").offset().top - $(window).height();
//  start movement when img is in view

    current = $(window).scrollTop();

    var newPosition = trackLength * (current/total);

    if (current > start) { // start anim
      //  go until half     
      if (current > start && current < (start+win)) {

        eleLeft.css({left:currPositionLeft + newPosition+'px'});
        eleRight.css({left:currPositionRight - newPosition+'px'});

      } else {
       //  return in the second half
        var newP = trackLength * (current/total)/10;

        eleLeft.css({left:currPositionLeft - (newP)+'px'});
        eleRight.css({left:currPositionRight + (newP)+'px'});
      }
    }
});
```

But I can't seem to grasp the Maths for returning the circles to their initial position.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Huangism thanks, I added the correct one

Comment: You can make the transition a bit smoother if you add `transition` for example `transition: left 0.5s;` to the left/right elements. Can't you save the position of the circles on page load and then just set left to the position when you want to reverse animate? with transition set, it will animate back smoothly

Comment: Also if your circles are the same, then just do https://jsfiddle.net/490b5r3L/1/ avoid the else altogether

Answer (score 0):

```js
// var current = $(window).scrollTop();
// var total = $(window).height() - current;

// select elements
// var eleRight = $(".from-right");
// var eleLeft = $(".from-left");

// select their start position
// var currPositionRight = eleRight.position().left;
// var currPositionLeft = eleLeft.position().left;

// var win = $(window).height()/2;
// var trackLength = $(window).width()/2; // movement should be from 0 to 50 vw

// $(".scroll-image").click(function(){

//   })

// 
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var x = $(".scroll-image").offset();
  var imageDivscroll = x.top;
  var Wheight = $(window).height() / 2;

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= imageDivscroll - Wheight) {
    $('.scroll-image').addClass('animate');
  } else {
    $('.scroll-image').removeClass('animate');
  }

  // var start = $(".circle").offset().top - $(window).height();
  //  start movement when img is in view

  // current = $(window).scrollTop();

  // var newPosition = trackLength * (current/total);

  // if (current > start) { // start anim
  //  go until half     
  //   if (current > start && current < (start+win)) {

  // eleLeft.css({left:currPositionLeft + newPosition+'px'});
  // eleRight.css({left:currPositionRight - newPosition+'px'});

  //   } else {
  //  return in the second half
  //         var newP = trackLength * (current/total)/10;

  //         eleLeft.css({left:currPositionLeft - (newP)+'px'});
  //         eleRight.css({left:currPositionRight + (newP)+'px'});
  //       }
  //     }
  // });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.section {
  padding: 4em;
  background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  min-height: 50vh;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.section:nth-child(even) {
  background: tomato;
}

.scroll-image {
  background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
  min-height: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  max-width: 25vw;
  max-height: 25vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.from-right {
  right: 0;
}

.from-left {
  left: 0;
}


/* Animation key frame */

.scroll-image {
  position: relative;
}

.scroll-image img:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.scroll-image img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.scroll-image.animate img:first-child {
  animation: leftSide 2s;
}

.scroll-image.animate img:last-child {
  animation: rigthSide 2s;
}

@keyframes leftSide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 46%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes rigthSide {
  0% {
    right: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    right: 46%;
  }
  100% {
    right: 0%;
  }
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <p class="font-weight-normal pr-xl-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit.
      Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin
      eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit.
      Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin
      eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="scroll-image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Purple_circle_100%25.svg/1024px-Purple_circle_100%25.svg.png" class="circle from-left" />
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Purple_circle_100%25.svg/1024px-Purple_circle_100%25.svg.png" class="circle from-right" />
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit.
      Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin
      eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit. </p>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h1>CONTENT</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam fringilla diam quis turpis eleifend, ac molestie diam consectetur. In at augue tellus. Pellentesque efficitur efficitur nisl, suscipit blandit mauris. Quisque consectetur tincidunt suscipit.
      Nullam fermentum dictum quam vel volutpat. Phasellus eleifend molestie neque id varius. Aenean convallis ornare nisi vitae blandit. Phasellus imperdiet, diam vel congue blandit, quam felis vehicula tellus, eget lacinia dui quam vel metus. Proin
      eleifend volutpat magna et convallis. Nam pharetra, orci eu aliquet efficitur, turpis leo consequat purus, sed fringilla metus arcu ac elit. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

it should be helpful for you

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it answers the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What does this code do? Please add an explanation so we can understand how this helps solve the issue!